# Close another process from node on Windows

Tags: node.js

How can I kill a process from node on Windows?

I'm making a updater. It needs close a windows executable (.exe) to download the updates. (The update process is download and overwrite). I read that this is possible with `process.kill(pid[, signal])`

But, How can I get the PID of the process if I know the name of the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html), you simply access the property.

```
process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGKILL');
```

This is a theoretical, untested, psuedo function that may help explain what I have in mind

```
exec('tasklist', (err, out, code) => { //tasklist is windows, but run command to get proccesses
    const id = processIdFromTaskList(processName, out); //get process id from name and parse from output of executed command
    process.kill(id, "SIGKILL"); //rekt
});
```

Comment: But it closes the node process or the other Windows process?

Comment: That will kill the node process. I'm not sure if Node is allowed to kill windows processes, but you can try to get them via [tasklist](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tasklist.mspx?mfr=true) (Possibly, store the results of an `exec` tasklist function, and process the results?)

Comment: I locate the PID of the process. What should I write in signal?

Comment: I'm not well versed on signals, but I would assume `SIGKILL`?

Comment: is "SIGKILL" a brutal killing command, or equivalent to a user trying to close the programs window?

Answer (score 1):

Use [node-windows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-windows) to get pid of process you want to kill so that you can call process.kill.  The library also provides an api to kill task.